# Signed magnitude, 1's complement and 2's complement of +46 and -17

Tags: binary, signed, complement

can anyone verify if am I correct?

```
+46 (7 bits)
S.M : 0101110
1's C. : 0101110 ( the same )
2's C. : 0101110 ( the same )

-17 (7 bits)
S.M : 1010001
1's C. : 1101110
2's C. : 1101111
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The +46 ones are all incorrect (your comment is correct).  To test the signed magnitude, just break down the magnitude component like:

```
0 * 1 + 
1 * 2 +
1 * 4 +
0 * 8 +
1 * 16 + 
1 * 32
```

Once you get the signed magnitude, the others should be easy.

Your -17 are all correct.

Comment: Yes indeed I missed that. it's 0101110.Thank you

Comment: But it is correct that it all stay the same when you have a + signed magnitude number?